# Super Courant algebroid

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

Is there SUSY Courant algebroid i.e. symplectic super Lie 2-algebroid or Courant algebroid over superspacetime or over supermanifold?

Comment: Currently you have many unregistered accounts. If you register one of your accounts, then you can get the other ones merged into it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to inform you about [Jeong-Hyuck Park's papers](http://arxiv.org/find/hep-th/1/au%3A+Park_J/0/1/0/all/0/1):

http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0069

http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5078

Comment: Currently you have many unregistered accounts. If you register one of your accounts, then you can get the other ones merged into it.